# Fixed element on background

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a footer that kind of appears from behind the other div element above.

[An example is the Pitchfork website with the footer on the bottom.](http://pitchfork.com/)

I tried to do this in CSS:

```
#footer {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#footer .text {
    position: fixed;
}
```

Or I could make it fixed and move it to the bottom of the page by setting a total height of the website. But that's just to complicated.

Any ideas or easy tutorials on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
#footer {
   position:fixed;
   left:0px;
   bottom:0px;
   height:30px;
   width:100%;
   background:#999;
}

/* IE 6 */
* html #footer {
   position:absolute;
   top:expression((0-(footer.offsetHeight)+(document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.clientHeight)+(ignoreMe = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop))+'px');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

assign this CSS to the footer:

```
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 150px; /* vaue as needed */
}
```

this fixes it at the bottom left and puts it behind the other elements (z-index -1)

In addition you have to add as much `margin-bottom` to the last element in the document flow as the height of the footer, so that the content can be scrolled above the footer, in my example 150px.